# Yii: how to add general parameter to the URL

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing

I would like to add some general purpose parameters to the URL. E.g.:

```
http://example.com/user/join?ref=bazuka_007
```

or

```
http://example.com/comments/123?simpleAuthToken=29c1urnfu9fh42183c43h1hc43814h0c
```

in case I would like to track from where users are coming to my site or auto-auth them.

How to orginize two things:

- Mixing beautified URLS and parameters.
- Handling general purpose parameter in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first example you can specify router rules as follows:

```
'rules'=>array(
    ...
    array('user/index/username/<username>', 'pattern'=>'user/<username:\w+>*'),
    ...
)
```

`http://example.com/user/join?ref=bazuka_007`

Will become:
`http://example.com/user/join/ref/bazuka_007`

nd get parameters will be

```
$_GET[username] = 'join';
$_GET[ref] = 'bazuka_007';
```

The second example can be made by analogy with the first.

**UPD:**

Also you can specify more common rules:

```
'rules'=>array(
    ...
    array('<controller>/index/param/<param>', 'pattern'=>'<controller:\w+>/<param:\.+>*'),
    ...
)
```

**UPD2:**

I guess if you want to do common logic for all requests then you should implement the logic in base controller and extend all your controllers from it.

Also you can inplement `beforeAction()` method in every controller wich will be invoked before an every action in controller.

Comment: ...which means that I'll have to modify each and every route I have on site to handle the same situation. It doesn't look like an adequate design.

Comment: @DenisKulagin I've just added an answer in the post.

Comment: But still, how and where do I handle common logic? E.g. I would like to save entry-page/ref to database for each page I specify ref for.

Comment: beforeAction is great, but how do I get custom parameters (e.g. ref, simpleAuthToken) in this common logic handler?

Comment: @DenisKulagin like usual get parameter (`$_GET['simpleAuthToken']`) or `Yii::app()->request->getParam('simpleAuthToken')`. Each pair of url's path between slashes will be added to get parameters as key=>value. For example: `http://example.com/user/join/ref/bazuka_007/var_2/val_2/var_3/val_3` in this request will be created following get params: `'ref'=>'bazuka_007', 'var_2'=>'val_2', 'var_3'=>'val_3'`

Comment: @DenisKulagin Not at all! Why not mark my answer as a 'answered'?!